# How to change the date format in the LXDM login/greeting screen (LXDE)

Tags: date, locale, lxde, display-manager

I found a number of resources to change the system (Archlinux 2016-03-01) date format, amongst others one to create a new format from an existing locale file.

I then modifed `/etc/environment` and later `/etc/locale.conf` to include `LC_TIME=xxx` in the hope that it would be the defaults used by LXDM, but that did not work although the `locale` shows the right LC_TIME.

Then I noticed that the date format is in fact different from any of the chosen locale's date formats anyway, so clearly the LXDM/GTK theme takes its format information somewhere else. I am unable however to find out which configuration file to tweak.

Any ideas or pointers?